# How to tell if a path points to an application in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, executable, shellexecute

If I have a file path (that might be later passed to the `ShellExecute` API) is there any way to tell if it points to an application?

I need this to work under Windows from a C++ program. Also, this path may contain start-up command line parameters.

Comment: Define "application."  That word spans many different types of files.

Comment: Yes, good point. Application path is a path to a file that can represent a process in a Windows kernel architecture.

Comment: It's really hard to define this. Do shortcuts count? Scripts? Documents (that, when double-clicked, open applications)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SaferiIsExecutableFileType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in order to check if the file is executable.

Comment: Thanks. Very weird name for an API, but it seems to do the job!

Answer (score 0):

So you really want to know if a string that represents a command line has the path to an executable as its first "part". How you go about this kind of depends on how accurate you want the information to be.

First, you have to parse the string to get the first argument. It's not as simple as just looking for the first space, because Windows paths can contain spaces. You'll have to handle things like `"c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://stackoverflow.com"`.

Searching for a file is a rather complicated process that involves searching the directories in the PATH environment variable. The [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function can help.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this doesn't seem as easy as it sounds. So in relation to SearchPath, OK, it's obvious if the extension is .exe, but as I pointed out below, what if the extension is missing?

Comment: Read the documentation for `SearchPath`, specifically the `lpExtension` parameter.